# Add wrapper to all images

Tags: 7, media

I want to add a wrapper to all images on my site in drupal 7. None of these images were inline elements so I can’t just directly edit the html code. I’m fairly new to drupal so I’m still figuring out how modules work and have no idea how to implement this. Any help?

Comment: Figure out how modules work, get an idea how to implement this, try it out yourself, and if you got stuck then come back and **we'd love to help you!** Everything else it pretty well documented all over the web and on https://drupal.org :)

Comment: If you are using an image field please see this question/answers https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29333/how-to-rewrite-the-ouput-html-of-the-image-field-for-a-node-page otherwise please ask something more specific